# What is the origin for the phrase "Lend a hand"?

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

does anyone know the origin of the phrase "Lend a hand"? I'm working on a paper about phrases and idioms and can't seem to find any history about it.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find a Youtube of the classic "give me a hand" scene from Get Smart.

Comment: Using ***lend*** instead of ***give*** has been part of English since the year dot (I doubt Shakespeare's ***Friends, Romans, countrymen, lend me your ears*** was linguistically groundbreaking). So you might as well ask who first used ***Give me a hand*** to mean ***Help me***. Or who first thought to call their female helper a ***handmaiden***.

Comment: See here: https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/40/messages/367.html

Comment: It could be *literal* when someone has fallen, needs rescuing, is stuck, can't lift something, etc. and needs physical help from your hand. In fact, **people** are often known as **hands**, for example the crew on a ship. A factory might be "short-handed" due to sickness.

Comment: When you give someone something it is a permanent transaction and to "give your hand" to someone is to marry them. When you lend something to someone it is a temporary transaction so when you "lend someone a hand" you are giving them the use of your hand (and the rest of your body and mind to which the hand is attached) on a temporary basis, usually until a specific task has been completed.

Comment: This expression is a rather apt example of [synecdoche](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/synecdoche).

Answer (score 3):

**lend a hand**  [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/107229?redirectedFrom=lend%20a%20hand#eid39300368)

> e. To afford the use or support of (a part of the body); esp. in **to
>   lend a hand** (or a helping hand)), to render assistance, assist,
>   help.

The OED cites early usage here:

> 1598   J. Florio Worlde of Wordes   The retainer doth some seruice,
>   that now and then..lendes a hande ouer a stile.

Answer (score 1):

In the literal sense of "offering one's hand" (e.g. to "shake" on an agreement) the phrase "lend a hand" appears in Chaucer's *Knight's Tale* (c1385):

> Lene me youre hond, for this is oure accord.

Chaucer also uses the verb in *Troilus and Criseyde*:

> And to Pandarus vois he lente his ere.

It's the verb **lenen**, to give, to offer, among other meanings, which sometimes appears as "lenden/lenten", sometimes "lenen".

The attestation in the OED from Florio's *A Worlde of Wordes* (1598), appears to me to be the literal meaning of "hand", not the figurative "assistance":

> The retainer doth some service, that now and then but holds your Honors styrrop, or lendes a hande over a stile, or opens a gappe for easier passage,  or holds a torch in a darke-waie...

Answer (score 0):

Lend a Hand was the motto for Brownies(Girl Guide Movement) back in England in the 4o's and 50's when I was a Brownie. It inspired us to look for ways to make a situation better for someone in need.

Comment: The existing answer says that the expression existed 350 years earlier than you suggest.

Comment: @Killing Time About the time of Girl Guido Fawkes?